# Getting Out of Memory exception possibly due to the ktable related state store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

We have a `kstreams` app doing `kstream-kstable` inner join. Both the topics are high volume with 256 partitions each. `kstreams` App is deployed on 8 nodes with 8 GB heap each right now. We see that the heap memory keeps constantly growing and eventually OOM happens. I am not able to get the heap dump as its running in a container which gets killed when that happens. But, I have tried a few things to gain confidence that it is related to the state stores/ktable related stuff. Without the below `RocksDBConfigSetter` the memory gets used up pretty quick, but with the below it is slowed down to some extent. Need some guidance to proceed further , thanks

I added below 3 properties,

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 1 * 1024L);
           properties.put(StreamsConfig.ROCKSDB_CONFIG_SETTER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomRocksDBConfig.class);
           properties.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);


public static class CustomRocksDBConfig implements RocksDBConfigSetter {

       
        private org.rocksdb.Cache cache = new org.rocksdb.LRUCache(1 * 1024L * 1024L);

        @Override
        public void setConfig(final String storeName, final Options options, final Map<String, Object> configs) {
            log.info("In CustomRocksDBConfig");

            BlockBasedTableConfig tableConfig = (BlockBasedTableConfig) options.tableFormatConfig();
            tableConfig.setBlockCache(cache);

            tableConfig.setBlockSize(1 * 1024L);

            tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocks(true);
            options.setTableFormatConfig(tableConfig);

            options.setMaxWriteBufferNumber(2);
        }

        @Override
        public void close(final String storeName, final Options options) {

            cache.close();
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is nothing but a repetition of the information that is available in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results looking for a solution to their problem - your current title doesn't't do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to limit the memory usage of RocksDB across all RocksDB instances on one node. To do so you must configure RocksDB to cache the index and filter blocks in the block cache, limit the memtable memory through a shared `WriteBufferManager` and count its memory against the block cache, and then pass the same `Cache` object to each instance. You can find more details and a sample configuration under

https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html#rocksdb

With such a setup you can specify a soft upper bound for the total heap used by all RocksDB state stores on one single instance (TOTAL_OFF_HEAP_MEMORY in the sample configuration) and then specify how much of that heap is used for writing to and reading from the state stores on one single node (TOTAL_MEMTABLE_MEMORY and INDEX_FILTER_BLOCK_RATIO in the sample configuration, respectively).

Since all values are app and workload specific you need to experiment with them and monitor the RocksDB state stores with the [metrics provided by Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#kafka_streams_rocksdb_monitoring).

Guidance how to handle RocksDB issues in Kafka Streams can be found under:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-tune-rocksdb-kafka-streams-state-stores-performance/

Especially for your case, the following section might be interesting:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-tune-rocksdb-kafka-streams-state-stores-performance/#high-memory-usage

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.I remember trying setting the write buffer manager etc before removing that from the config setter.  May be the values I specified were not correct for those different parameters.  It will be helpful if you can just for my understanding purposes specify some values for TOTAL_OFF_HEAP_MEMORY, TOTAL_MEMTABLE_MEMORY, INDEX_FILTER_BLOCK_RATIO, BLOCK_SIZE & MEMTABLE_SIZE for a 8GB ram and 8 instances with each having 32 partitions of the state store (topic has 256 total partitions) or in general .

Comment: Just to make sure I dont set one value higher than the other when it should be the other way around.

Comment: Also note: While 32 partitions per instance is ideal and Kafka Streams tries to do its best to achieve this distribution, Kafka Streams does not guarantee the ideal distribution. So you need also to plan for some skewness and for the case where a node crashes and RocksDB instances of the crashed node are migrated to the other seven remaining node.

Comment: In your example in the question the RocksDB cache is not defined as static. Hence, it is not shared among all RocksDB instances of the same node.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I will make it static and experiment with the config values.